# Why is this type not assignable to the parameter type?

Tags: c#, automapper

The `OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonths` return type is a copy of the `OWF_ManagerRelationshipViewModel` a couple things in it commented out.  This method is a modified version of the original that used `OWF_ManagerRelationshipViewModel` as the return type.  The goal is to eliminate one of the proxy classes to reduce the number of records being returned.

One other difference is passing in the the new `OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel` to `automapper` in the return statement.

I get a red squiggle under the item in `managerListFinal.Add(item);` and `(managerListFinal)` in the `automapper` part of the return type.

The first red squiggle in the `managerListFinal.Add(item);` says:

> 'Argument type Jupiter.Core.Model.OWF_ManagerRelationship is not
>   assignable to parameter type
>   Jupiter.Core.Model.OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel'.

The second red squiggle in `(managerListFinal)` says:

> 'Argument type Jupiter.Core.Model.OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel
>   is not assignable to parameter type
>   Jupiter.Core.Model.OWF_ManagerRelationship'.

I tried also returning the `managerListFinal` below the `automapper` return, but get a message that says same thing as it did for the first one above that uses the `automapper`.

The new `OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel` was created with out the Document request list in an effort to not return these records.  I thought it would work because it's so similar the original `OWF_ManagerRelationshipViewModel`.

I think the `automapper` return would return what I need, if it worked correctly.  I'm trying to get the onsites dates, Target dates, usernames and manager types.  The onsite and target dates are used in the method below while the  DisplayName, Manager Type and Users are displayed in the view's grid.

I thought this would be as simple as copying the viewmodel and ommiting the doc request list portion of it.  I don't understand why the compiler doesn't like this or how to correct it.

Original OWF_ManagerRelationshipViewModel:

```
public class OWF_ManagerRelationshipViewModel 
{
    public OWF_ManagerRelationshipViewModel()
    {
        OWF_Onsites = new List<OWF_OnsitesViewModel>();
        OWF_DocumentRequestList = new List<OWF_DocumentRequestListViewModel>();
    }

    public int RelationshipId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public string Users { get; set; }
    public string ManagerType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string CurrentState { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<OWF_AccessGroupViewModel> UsernameList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OWF_DocumentRequestListViewModel> OWF_DocumentRequestList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OWF_OnsitesViewModel> OWF_Onsites { get; set; }
}
```

My new OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel:

```
     public class OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel 
{
    public OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel()
    {
        //OWF_DocumentRequestList = new List<OWF_DocumentRequestListViewModel>();
        OWF_Onsites = new List<OWF_OnsitesViewModel>();
    }

    public int RelationshipId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public string Users { get; set; }             
    public string ManagerType { get; set; }         

    [Required]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string CurrentState { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<OWF_AccessGroupViewModel> UsernameList { get; set; }                                 
    //public virtual ICollection<OWF_DocumentRequestListViewModel> OWF_DocumentRequestList { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<OWF_OnsitesViewModel> OWF_Onsites { get; set; }
}
```

Method with the red squiggles:

```
        public IEnumerable<OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel> GetAllExistingManagersByCurrentDate()
    {
        var managers = _relationshipRepo.GetAll();
        var managerListFinal = new List<OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel>();
        var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        var prevYear = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year;

        foreach (var item in managers)
        {
            foreach (var onsite in item.OWF_Onsites.Where(x => x.OnsiteDate != null))
            {
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Month == DateTime.Now.Month && Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Year == year  ||
                    onsite.TargetMonth == DateTime.Now.Month && onsite.OnsiteDate == null && Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Year == year ||
                    onsite.TargetMonth == (DateTime.Now.Month + 1) && onsite.OnsiteDate == null && Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Year == year ||
                    Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Month == (DateTime.Now.Month + 1) && Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Year == year ||
                    Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Month == DateTime.Now.Month && Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Year == prevYear ||
                    onsite.TargetMonth == DateTime.Now.Month && onsite.OnsiteDate == null && Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Year == prevYear ||
                    onsite.TargetMonth == (DateTime.Now.Month + 1) && onsite.OnsiteDate == null && Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Year == prevYear ||
                    Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Month == (DateTime.Now.Month + 1) && Convert.ToDateTime(onsite.OnsiteDate).Year == prevYear)
                {
                    managerListFinal.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        //return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OWF_ManagerRelationship>, IEnumerable<OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel>>(managerListFinal);
        return managerListFinal;
    }
```

Comment: I was to lazy to read the whole bloated text, so I started by searching for questionmarks `?` in the text in order to read the full actual question. Turns out there is no question other than the headline. I suggest you re-read your text and edit the question.

Comment: I made a few (minor) edits to the formatting to make it a little easier to read, but as @grek40 said, you may want to revisit this question and try to make it clearer what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You take items from OWF_ManagerRelationship check them and then place them into a list of OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel. and afterwards you want to map them.

I think you should do something like this

```
managerListFinal.Add(Mapper.Map<OWF_ManagerRelationship,OWF_ManagersNextTwoMonthsViewModel>(item));
```

and you should be good